# Javascript: WRite in Div Class

Tags: javascript

Trying to write some random text in a created div class with javascript.  I know how to do it with HTML -> Javascript but I can't get it to work with just pure Javascript

```
var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
mydiv.className="first";

document.getElementsByClassName("first").innerHTML="hi";
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("first")` returns an array so `document.getElementsByClassName("first")[0].innerHTML = 'hi'`

Comment: also need to make sure the div is added to the dom before making the `document.getElementsByClassName()` request

Comment: You could just say `mydiv.innerHTML="hi";` - since `mydiv` refers to the div element

Comment: It would be better if you did it this way: `mydiv.innerHTML = "hi";`.

Comment: But if you also want the text to be displayed in the page... then you need to add the new div to the dom

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5bso784t/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5bso784t/2/

Comment: Thanks, it worked, something so simple took me an hour to figure out

Comment: @Snorlax which one is the solution you were looking for

Comment: I liked the first jsfiddle one with appendCHild